# ERROR ORA-00937 when trying to select another attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to project the highest average GPA of the students by majors.

It works if I don't SELECT `major` and leave it out.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT  MAX(avg_gpa), major
FROM    (SELECT major, AVG(gpa) AS avg_gpa
        FROM Student
        GROUP BY  major);
```

My error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
  MAX(avg_gpa) as max_avg_gpa, 
  min(major) keep (dense_rank first order by avg_gpa desc) as best_major
FROM (
  SELECT 
    major, 
    AVG(gpa) AS avg_gpa
  FROM Student
  GROUP BY  major
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked perfectly. But how would I go about doing it modifying line 3? I have not learned some of the syntax used there.